# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in E$ iff $f_i$ is differentiable at $x$ for every $1 \leq i \leq m$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, derivatives, metric-spaces

> Let $E$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f: E \to \mathbb{R}^m$
>   and $f = (f_1,f_2,...,f_m)$ where $f_i : E \to \mathbb{R}$ for $1 \leq
>  i \leq m$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in E$ iff $f_i$ is
>   differentiable at $x$ for every $1 \leq i \leq m$.

I am stuck even after reading the solution: we prove the only if part:

Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x$. By the definition of differentiability in metric spaces, there exists $m \times n$ matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ such that $$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||}{||h||} = 0$$

Now what i do not understand is how the solution derive the following part:

For $u = \begin{pmatrix}u_1 \\u_2 \\ \vdots \\u_m\\ \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we have $|u_i| \leq ||u||$ for all $i$ (this part i can understand).

Then it says $$\dfrac{|f_i(x+h)-f_i(x)-(a_{i1}~ \cdots ~ a_{in})h|}{||h||} \leq \dfrac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah||}{||h||}$$

This step is the step that i cannot derive, is there any intermediate steps to show me the inequality holds?

Comment: Use the fact that $|u_i|\le\|u\|$,  (the part you can understand) in the special case of $u=f(x+h)=f(x)-Ah$ in the last displayed formula.

Comment: oh i see, you mean treat $u = f(x+h) - f(x) - Ah$ right?

Comment: Sorry about the typo.  Yes, I meant $u=f(x+h)-f(x) - Ah$.  Good spotting!

Comment: ok thanks @kimchilover i got it now